# Проблема с Core Dump при работе в Processing

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

Работаю на ноутбуке с Линукс Минт. Стоит Oracle JRE. Недавно скачал Processing (версия 3.0.1.). При первом запуске все работает, после перезагрузки вылетает. Вот что написано в логах

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x12d16]  readCEN+0xb46
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Команду вводил под рутом, processing все равно не работает. Переустановка помогает ровно на один раз

Comment: 1. *Команду вводил под рутом* — зачем? 2. и вообще — вам что именно нужно? чтобы core dump сохранялся?

Comment: To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Answer (score 1):

> To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

это рекомендация, как разрешить создание [дампа памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) при падении программы.

если вы не разработчик программы *java*, то дамп памяти вряд ли чем-то вам поможет. в любом случае, включение дампа памяти не поможет исправить ошибку.

возможно, имеет смысл обратиться в техподдержку программы, которую вы запускаете — *processing*.